# Granting Same Database Role on All Databases SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to grant a user the same role on all databases?  Server-level roles only grant server specific options to users.  I'd like to grant a user read-only access to all DBs on a server

Comment: [sp_MSforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sp_MSforeachdb`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) might do the trick for you:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb '
    use [?];
    declare @user sysname = ''MyUserName''
    if db_name() not in (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')
    begin
        if not exists (
            select null
            from dbo.sysusers
            where name = @user
        )
        begin
            print ''Adding '' + @user + '' to '' + db_name();
            exec sp_grantdbaccess @user, @user;
        end;
    print ''Granting '' + @user + '' read access to '' + db_name();
    exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, @user;
    end;
'
```